# SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake

Tags: java, ssl, youtube-data-api

**1.Analyze the phenomenon**

Similar exceptions and keyword on the upload Youtube failed:

SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake and EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Case1:

```
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1392)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:167)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
some code.

com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:591)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:474)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:550)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:384)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeUploadInitiation(MediaHttpUploader.java:525)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:568)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.executeCurrentRequestWithoutGZip(MediaHttpUploader.java:551)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:996)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:79)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:108)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:264)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1317)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1342)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:435)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1300)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1400)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1570)
    2022-03-04 03:27:27 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    2022-03-04 03:27:27
```

**2.Context**
According to the logs, the above error occurred when calling the Youtube APIs while uploading a video, but this is not frequent, and it has occurred twice in about 2 weeks in production.

**3.Now doubts are as follows**

Case1 :

Youtube or proxy(if there is) actively close the connection?

The local network is unstable?

Pods SLB effect？

Case2:

Youtube service stopped?

The local network is unstable?

Processing takes longer than timeout？

The amount of host bandwidth at the relevant time?

Comment: "Youtube or proxy(if there is) actively close the connection?" Yes. "The local network is unstable?" No.

Comment: ty,Why the connection is actively closed?